# Spring MVC 3.2.3 Tiles 2 HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I'm developing a web application with **Spring MVC** using **Tiles**.When I run my app,I encounter **HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception**

**Development Environment**

```
 - Spring MVC 3.2.3 Release
 - Tiles 2.2.1  
     tiles-core-2.2.1.jar
     tiles-template-2.2.1.jar
     tiles-jsp-2.2.1.jar
     tiles-servlet-2.2.1.jar
     tiles-api-2.2.1.jar
     tiles-request-api-1.0.1.jar
```

**File locations**

[image: File locations]

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">

        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView">
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>
                    WEB-INF/tiles.xml
                </value>
            </list>

        </property>
    </bean>
```

**tiles.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">      

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition"
        template="/WEB-INF/views/templates/template1/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/templates/components/header.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="menu"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/templates/components/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>


    <definition name="menu"
               preparer="menuController"
               template="/WEB-INF/views/templates/components/menu.jsp">
    </definition>
    <definition name="secondary.definition"
         template="/WEB-INF/views/templates/template2/layout2.jsp" preparer="menuController">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/templates/components/header.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/templates/components/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="anasayfa" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Anasayfa" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="kategori" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Kategori" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/kategori.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="kod" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Kod" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/kod.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="login" extends="secondary.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Login" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="kayit" extends="secondary.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Kayit" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/kayit.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="upload" extends="secondary.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Ek" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/upload.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="kullanici" extends="secondary.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Kullanici" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/kullanici.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactoryException: Cannot load definition URLs
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactoryException: Cannot load definition URLs
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.getSourceURLs(TilesConfigurer.java:428)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createLocaleDefinitionDao(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:298)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createDefinitionsFactory(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:242)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.createDefinitionsFactory(TilesConfigurer.java:481)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:124)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(TilesConfigurer.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/
                    WEB-INF/tiles.xml
                ] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringTilesApplicationContextFactory$SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext.getResources(SpringTilesApplicationContextFactory.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.getSourceURLs(TilesConfigurer.java:423)
    ... 42 more

Tem 17, 2014 12:18:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /controller threw load() exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/
                    WEB-INF/tiles.xml
                ] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringTilesApplicationContextFactory$SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext.getResources(SpringTilesApplicationContextFactory.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.getSourceURLs(TilesConfigurer.java:423)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createLocaleDefinitionDao(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:298)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createDefinitionsFactory(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:242)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.createDefinitionsFactory(TilesConfigurer.java:481)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:124)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(TilesConfigurer.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Briefly stack trace I got this exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/
                WEB-INF/tiles.xml
            ] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

How can I solve this problem?Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your files really where you say they are in the tiles.xml?

Comment: @Engineer Dollery,Yes,they are in the location which is defined in the tiles.xml

Comment: Try adding a leading slash (`/WEB-INF/tiles.xml`)

Comment: @pmorken ,Thanks for yoyr comment,but when try with slash i got  `ServletContext resource [/                              / WEB-INF/tiles.xml
            ] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist` exception

Comment: It looks from the error message that there might be a space between the slash and WEB-INF/tiles.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is unable to find tiles file make sure your path to tiles.xml is correct

This is correct

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>

        </property>
    </bean>
```

Incorrect way

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
             \\This may lead to leading space in path
                <value>
                    WEB-INF/tiles.xml
                </value>
            </list>

        </property>
    </bean>
```